# ECMAScript Script Jobs. Как инициировать работу этого типа?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

ECMAScript [определяет](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) 2 типа работ как обязательные: Promise Jobs и Script Jobs. Ситуация с Promise Jobs понятна: создал себе Promise или асинхронную функцию - и все, новая Promise Job создана и добавлена в очередь.

Но как обстоит дело со Script Jobs? Что нужно сделать, чтобы создать работу этого типа?

Знаю, что к Script Jobs относятся также код модулей. Но разве при импортировании модуля его код не выполняется сразу же? Хотя спецификация говорит, что работы для того и нужны, чтобы "откладываться" и выполняться позже (как в ситуации с Promise'ами).

Короче говоря, что нужно сделать, чтобы инициировать новую работу и добавить ее в очередь Script Jobs?

Comment: добавь ссылку на спецификацию, откуда ты определения и описания взял

Comment: @Grundy в первом абзаце привёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственное упоминание ScriptJob с точки зрения постановки в очередь относится к пункту [8.6 RunJobs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-runjobs) - на втором шаге написано:

> 2. In an implementation-dependent manner, obtain the ECMAScript source texts (see clause 10) and any associated host-defined values for zero or more ECMAScript scripts and/or ECMAScript modules. For each such sourceText and hostDefined, do [...]

Тут написано примерно следующее: надо выбрать те скрипты, которым суждено исполняться - и положить их в очередь. Далее на третьем шаге описывается их исполнение по порядку.

В свою очередь, RunJobs в других местах спецификации не упоминается, это точка входа.

---

Получается, ScriptJob - это любой код, который хост решил загрузить и исполнить по каким бы то ни было причинам. Ключевой момент данного описания - в том, что постановка ScriptJob в очередь и исполнение **всех** очередей - два этапа одной и той же операции RunJobs, таким образом в соответствии со спецификацией невозможно исполнить произвольный код и при этом не исполнить ожидающих продолжений (PromiseJob).

Зачем все так сложно расписано - я не знаю. Видимо, они пытаются сделать такую спецификацию чтобы ее нельзя было в принципе прочитать по-разному <s>*(или просто нельзя было прочитать)*</s>

Comment: Выходит, что исполнение main скрипта, допустим, на странице в браузере подразумевает, что этот скрипт сначала кладется в очередь, а потом тут же из этой очереди изымается и выполняется?

Comment: Да. Но как раз на странице в браузере может быть подключена целая куча скриптов, причем часть из них - отложено или асинхронно (с атрибутами defer или async).

Comment: Но ведь это все равно не объясняет проблему модулей: если код модуля тоже кладется в очередь во время исполнения главного скрипта, то каким образом он выполняется (а мы ведь имеем доступ к функциям, полученным из модулей уже во время выполнения главного скрипта), если спецификация в той же части, что я привел в вопросе явно говорит, что 2 работы из одной очереди не могут выполняться одновременно?

Comment: То есть если код модуля выполняется только после того, как выполнился главный скрипт, то откуда этот главный скрипт имеет доступ к тому, что импортируется модулем?

Comment: @smellyshovel любой модуль начинает выполняться строго после своих зависимостей. Пока хотя бы один импорт не загружен или не выполнен - не исполнится ни строчки вашего кода.

Comment: В том-то и дело. Как код модулей может выполнится, если он стоит в очереди *после* главного скрипта? Ведь это *главный скрипт* добавляет модуль в очередь.

Comment: Мы ведь об одних и тех же импортах говорим, я надеюсь? Я говорю о import statement'ах внутри JavaScript кода, а не об подключении дополнительных скриптов, например, из HTML.

Comment: Так, нет, вру. Там отдельно определяются главный модуль (top level module) и его зависимости; зависимости не являются отдельной задачей.

Comment: Я именно об этом и говорю. Вот начинает скрипт выполняться. Там есть import. Этот модуль, объявленный в импорте, добавляется в очередь Script Jobs. Сам скрипт при этом продолжает исполняться. И дальше там есть обращения к функциям, которые объявляет этот модуль. Но ведь модуль еще к этому времени не исполнится, он только добавился в очередь? Тогда почему скрипт выполняется без ошибок?

Comment: *"Вот начинает скрипт выполняться. Там есть import."* - **Неверно!** К моменту выполнения модуля все импорты уже зарезолвлены. См. пункт 6 в процедуре [15.2.1.19 Runtime Semantics: TopLevelModuleEvaluationJob](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-toplevelmoduleevaluationjob)

Comment: Вот теперь все стало на свои места. Благодарю за объяснения. И еще попрошу вас в ближайшее время эти комментарии не удалять. Ну или перенести их в тело ответа. Спасибо!